# DropDownList selectedvalue and tables

Tags: asp.net, linq, file, drop-down-menu

Q:

Hi,I have a dropdownlist and i get two errors.

***Error #1:*** My requirement is selecting the meeting name from the dropdownlist, saving it into a string and using that string later. I want to get the field value (which gives me the path where the files are stored) from the database table.

**The code :**

```
string selected = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

var query = from meet in db.Meets
            where meet.Summary = selected
            select meet.Doc_Path;
```

I get an error at "`where meet.Summary=selected`" and it says

> "cannot implicitly convert type string
>   to bool"

***Error #2:*** I wish to use the `Doc_Path` value which I get through the query. I am not sure of the syntax and hence getting an error when I tried it.

**The code:**

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(query);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error # 1 -** I think you need == instead of just =

```
string selected = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

var query = from meet in db.Meets
            where meet.Summary == selected
            select meet.Doc_Path;
```

**Error #2 -** You may need to user `Server.MapPath`

```
String FilePath;
FilePath = Server.MapPath(query);
```

or, to combine them

```
string selected = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

var query = from meet in db.Meets
            where meet.Summary == selected
            select Server.MapPath(meet.Doc_Path);

string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(query);
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. First error got resolved but its not taking "string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(query);". Compiler is expecting a string type argument for GetDirectories. Even if I do query.ToString() still not working

Comment: its taking query.ToString() as a SQL query where as I don't want that... I want the result of the query to be passed on.

Answer (score 0):

**Error # 1:**

As said before ,you should use `==` instead of `=` when making comparison .

**Error # 2:**

Why you use `Directory.GetDirectories(query);`

the previous method is used to Get the names of subdirectories (including their paths) in the specified directory.

look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx)

i think you don't need this method, just use :

```
string selected = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

var query = from meet in db.Meets
            where meet.Summary == selected
            select meet.Doc_Path;

string dirPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + query.ToString();
```

**Make sure that the `meet.Doc_Path` value is n't the absolute path, store only the relative path.**